# Why is the solution of the Klein-Gordon PDE a distribution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I've also posted this question on [physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/791466/why-is-the-general-solution-of-the-klein-gordon-equation-a-distribution) in case it is more appropiate there.

Consider the Klein-Gordon equation:
$$(\square + m^2)\phi = (\partial_t^2 - \Delta + m^2)\phi = 0 \tag{1}$$
The solution to this equation is typically obtained by writing $\phi$ as an inverse Fourier transform:
$$\phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{i (k \cdot x)} \hat{\phi}(t,k) d^3k$$
and then substituting this into (1) to get
$$(\partial_t^2 - k^2 + m^2)\hat{\phi} = 0. \tag{2}$$

From here it is often stated that the general solution to (2) must be a distribution, but why is this?

Comment: Is this of any help? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1511505/532409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a very physical one: All wave equations
$$f(t+dt,x)-2f(t,x)+f(t-dt,x) = \text{mean}(f(t,x+\xi), |\xi| < \epsilon \ )$$
are local maps of amplitude and rapidity   $$(f(t,x),\partial_t f(t,x))  \to (f(t+dt,x),\partial_t f(t+dt,x)). $$ In the easiest case of free linear, time- and space independent coefficients the map is a simple shift in space
$$(f(t,x),\partial_t f(t,x))  \to (f(t,x-c dt),\partial_t f(t,x-c dt)) $$
So the translation map is working on functions f without any smoothness requirements. Since smoothness means summability of the energy of Fourier modes, the wave equation has applications far wider than states in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of insight I was looking for!